# Logs not showing in Google Cloud Logging UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud, google-cloud-logging, spring-cloud-gcp

I'm trying to set up sending my application logs to Google Cloud Logging, but no matter what I try, the logs are not visible in the Log Viewer.

I tried:

- using the [Java Logging Logback](https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging-logback) appender directly, following all of the steps in the documentation, setting different combinations of parameters
- using [Spring Cloud GCP](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gcp), again following all of the tutorials and trying different configurations
- using the CLI to write log entries, using the examples from the docs
- using the API explorer to write log entries, providing all of the required fields

The Log ingestion tab shows that the data is actually ingested and I am able to retrieve the entries using `gcloud logging read` or using the API explorer.

Unfortunately, the logs are not showing up in the viewer, which greets me with

> [..] You do not have any logs in your project right now.

The logging API is, of course, enabled (I guess I wouldn't be able to get the CLI/API explorer to work without it).

Any clues what's wrong? Can it be that my logging entries have invalid format or are missing some key bit of information?

Attaching a couple of log entries, just in case. First was created by the API, second one was sent from the app:

```
insertId: 1mty0nhg3b7x2xx
logName: projects/my-project/logs/test.log
receiveTimestamp: '2020-05-25T11:18:57.565490347Z'
resource:
  labels:
    project_id: my-project
  type: global
severity: INFO
textPayload: It works!
timestamp: '2020-05-25T11:18:57.565490347Z'
```

```
insertId: cs0e1zg1qqxxx6
labels:
  levelName: INFO
  levelValue: '20000'
  loggerName: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
logName: projects/my-project/logs/spring.log
receiveTimestamp: '2020-05-24T16:37:47.275614395Z'
resource:
  labels:
    project_id: my-project
  type: global
severity: INFO
textPayload: Completed initialization in 17 ms
timestamp: '2020-05-24T16:37:47.234Z'
```

EDIT: I found a temporary workaround. I created a second project, wrote a short lambda that logs a message, and was able to see the logs for the lambda in that project. When I switched to the new "preview" mode, and changed project to the original one, I can now see the logs. However, when I switch back to "classic" mode, it still says that there are no logs in the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am from the Cloud Logging team. This was a known issue with metadata ingestion for some projects. This is now fixed.

The metadata is used by the Logs Viewer to detect the types of logs that are present, and they also show up in the Logs Viewer menus. Due to an issue with metadata ingestion for some projects, either some menu items went missing or for brand new projects, logs viewer would only show a welcome banner. Please check again if this is now fixed.

Comment: I can't check it anymore because I deleted the project but thanks for letting me know!

Comment: When I try to see logs for cloud run (logs tab) in browser all I get is "Internal error encountered"

Answer (score 1):

I think I tried everything by now and I believe there's just something wrong with that particular project.

I followed through on the walkaround that I edited into the question and created a completely new project. I ran a lambda function which logged a line to make sure both classical and preview modes of the viewer are working. Finally, I moved all of my resources to the new project.